# How to get rails to work with jruby and rvm - ruby version keeps flipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, jruby

Migrating a rails app's gem file from

```
"ruby '2.5.1'"
```

(runs fine) to

```
"ruby '2.5.1', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.1.17.0'"
```

I have modified the environment using:

```
rvm use jruby-9.1.17.0
```

yet when I run bundle install I get

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1
```

other info:

```
    ~$ rvm current 
    jruby-9.1.17.0
    ~$ rvm list
    => jruby-9.1.17.0 [ x86_64 ]
   jruby-9.2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p318 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p330 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p576 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

I can't see where the 2.3.3  version is coming from!
Any ideas? Am using MacOS and RVM

Comment: What is `~$ rvm current` and `~$ rvm list` says? Maybe, you have `.versions.conf` or `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files?

Comment: thanks - have added the first 2. where would I find those 3 files located?

Comment: What about run `bundle install` such way: `jruby -S bundle install`?
And what `$ jruby --version` says?
- where would I find those 3 files located? - look for that at application root path

Comment: `2.3.3` version also may comes from your IDE default settings

Comment: jruby --version 
jruby 9.1.17.0 (2.3.3) 2018-04-20 d8b1ff9 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.25-b02 on 1.8.0_25-b17 +jit [darwin-x86_64]

all those files are empty, other than .ruby-version that says: ruby-2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is says is definitely worth following :

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1
```

if you do a `rvm jruby-9.1.17.0 do ruby --version` you will get smt like :

```
jruby 9.1.17.0 (2.3.3) 2018-04-20 d8b1ff9 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.171-b11 on 1.8.0_171-b11 +jit [linux-x86_64]
```

the **(2.3.3)** part means its Ruby 2.3 so I recommend you use JRuby 9.2 :

```
rvm install jruby-9.2.8.0
```

will give you a **2.5(.3)** compatible Ruby runtime, update *Gemfile* accordingly :

```
"ruby '2.5.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.2.8.0'"
```

Comment: great spot - i couldn't understand where the 2.3.3 was coming from. all set now.